# How do I remove ImportError

Tags: python, numpy

I constructed a code for downloading dataset using Bing API. When I ran it on terminal, it returns following error:

```
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "search_bing_api.py", line 12, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/home/kaustubhj/.virtualenvs/dl4cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

So I upgraded numpy but its no use

So what should I do ?

Comment: just verifying, is the numpy package in the same python env as the python that you are running?

Comment: yes it is in the same python env

Answer (score 0):

Do you have NumPy installed? If not, please run the code after downloading it via cmd by writing `pip install numpy`.

Comment: yes I have installed numpy

Comment: There might be 2 possible cases, either you have 2 versions of NumPy or some other file also named as numpy.py